# uncheck checkbox and radio button using Reactjs using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i want to uncheck my checkbox but it does uncheck but just after unchecking it gives error

```
    console.log()

    var x = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
    for(let i=0; i<=x.length; i++) {
      x[i].Checked = false;
      }   
  }

<button onClick={() => clearClickHandler()}>Clear all filter</button>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" defaultChecked={false} onChange={() => sortDispatch({payload: "INCLUDE_OUT_OF_STOCK"})}></input>
          Include out of stock
        </label>
```

Comment: Direct DOM mutations are anti-pattern in React. Also, what is the error?

Comment: @DrewReese yes DOM mutation are anti-patter but i do not get any other way, the erros is
```
  159 | 
  160 |   var x = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
  161 |   for(let i=0; i<=x.length; i++) {
> 162 |     x[i].Checked = false;
      | ^  163 |     }   
  164 | }
  165 | 
```

Comment: How many checkboxes are you working with?

Comment: @OssaijaThankgod for now 1 but i need to add more once it get done and also need to clear radio button afterward

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

Direct DOM mutations are anti-pattern in React and even if it wasn't throwing an error since the change happens ***outside*** of React, React won't be aware of the change and won't rerender the UI.

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
  x[i].Checked = false; // <-- mutation!!! should probably also be `.checked`
}
```

## Solution

You can use [Fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

> In order to reset the value when moving to a different item (as in our
> password manager scenario), we can use the special React attribute
> called `key`. When a `key` changes, React will [*create a new component
> instance rather than update the current one*](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys). Keys are usually used for
> dynamic lists but are also useful here.

Here's an example demo applying using a React key against a set of inputs.

```
function App() {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);

  const clearClickHandler = () => setKey((k) => k + 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Fragment key={key}> // <-- React key updates will "reset" inputs
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" defaultChecked={false} />
          Include out of stock
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" defaultChecked={false} />
          Include out of stock
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" defaultChecked={false} />
          Include out of stock
        </label>
      </Fragment>

      <div>
        <button onClick={clearClickHandler}>Clear all filter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit uncheck-checkbox-and-radio-button-using-reactjs-using-props]

Comment: yes it resets the checkbox, but the functionality that Include out of stock holds does not get reset, but still its useful to clear checkbox, thank you

Comment: @Manan Are you referring to the action that is dispatched by the `onChange` handler? You should probably not commit to updating any redux state until you know for sure the checkbox values. Or use a more substantial form management library like redux-from, react-final-form, etc... these can handle their own internal state and resetting, etc. The alternative is to switch over to [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) so you can imperatively reset their values and the `onChange` handles updating the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

You can create refs attached to the elements you want to check and uncheck programmatically.

Then have a functions that manages the unchecking

```
uncheckAll() {
    // the length of the array below should
   //  depend on the numbers of ref you have

   [1].forEach((refId) => this.refs[`ref_${refId}`].unCheck)
}
```

Note: this assumes your components are based on class

```
<input type="checkbox" ref="check_1" defaultChecked={false} onChange={() => sortDispatch({payload: "INCLUDE_OUT_OF_STOCK"})}></input>
      Include out of stock
    </label>
```